# TSQL Pivot Long List of Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am looking to use pivot function to convert row values of a column into separate columns. There are 100+ distinct values in that column and hard-coding each and every single value in the 'for' clause of the pivot function would be very time consuming and not good from maintainability purposes. I was wondering if there is any easier way to tackle this problem?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 5):

You can use Dynamic SQL in a `PIVOT` for this type of query.  Dynamic SQL will get the list of the items that you want to transform on execution which prevents the need to hard-code each item:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.condition_id) 
            FROM t c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT memid, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select MemId, Condition_id, condition_result
                from t
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(condition_result)
                for condition_id in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4891/2)

If you post a sample of data that you need to transform, then I can adjust my query to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this and had db2 Data like this.

```
id,MCD1,MCD2,MCD3,MCD4
1,4,5,4,3
2,6,7,8,9
3,3,6,2,6
4,2,5,8,4
5,3,4,5,6
```

I wrote this Dynamic SQL in TSQL

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',', COLUMN_NAME FROM my_db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'PivotLonger' AND COLUMN_NAME like 'MCD%'
 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT id, MCD, Value
                from [my_db].[dbo].[PivotLonger]
                UNPIVOT  
               (Value FOR MCD IN (' + @cols + ')) AS unpvt'

execute(@query)
```

Resulted in expanding the columns into a nice long table :)

```
id,MCD,Value
1,MCD1,4
1,MCD2,5
1,MCD3,4
1,MCD4,3
2,MCD1,6
2,MCD2,7
2,MCD3,8
2,MCD4,9
3,MCD1,3
3,MCD2,6
3,MCD3,2
3,MCD4,6
4,MCD1,2
4,MCD2,5
4,MCD3,8
4,MCD4,4
5,MCD1,3
5,MCD2,4
5,MCD3,5
5,MCD4,6
```