# TSQL how to specify column list range for PIVOT?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

The SELECT statement below is from a **stored procedure** I am using to retrieve data which is subsequently sent to JSON:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(DateTimeUTC as SmallDateTime) as [DateTime], DataValue, VariableID
    FROM DataValues
    WHERE SiteID = @siteID and VariableID BETWEEN 9 and 10 and DateTimeUTC >= DATEADD (day, @pastDays, getdate())
     ) TableDate
PIVOT (SUM(DataValue) FOR VariableID IN ([9],[10])) PivotTable ORDER BY [DateTime]
```

What I would like to accomplish is to modify the procedure to accept a column range to pivot. In the above example I am only retrieving values for two variables.  What if I want to retrieve VariableID 1 through 10, or 1 through 50?  There has to be a way to retrieve 1 through 10 in a way other than:

```
 VariableID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])
```

The [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.105%29.aspx) on MSDN doesn't mention a way to specify a range.

I realize that it is possible to use dynamic SQL in a stored procedure, but given my own knowledge of SQL and the knowledge of those who will have to maintain this long term I am hesitant to introduce additional complexity by using dynamic SQL. There is a conceptually similar question on here, see [TSQL Pivot Long List of Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883957/tsql-pivot-long-list-of-columns), and it was answered with a dynamic SQL solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server - Rows to Columns without Aggregation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857737/sql-server-rows-to-columns-without-aggregation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `PIVOT` function does not have the ability to generate the list of columns, without using dynamic sql.

So your SQL code will be similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(VariableID) 
                    from DataValues
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [DateTime], ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                SELECT CAST(DateTimeUTC as SmallDateTime) as [DateTime], 
                    DataValue, 
                    VariableID
                FROM DataValues
                WHERE SiteID = '+cast(@siteID as varchar(10))+'
                    -- and VariableID BETWEEN 9 and 10 -- remove the variableID filter
                    and DateTimeUTC >= DATEADD (day, +'cast(@pastDays as varchar(10))+', getdate())
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                SUM(DataValue)
                for VariableID in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

The key to this is the following code which generates the list of `variableIds` to become columns:

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(VariableID) 
                    from DataValues
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

This will create the list of all `distinct` variable id's. This list is then added to the SQL query string to return.

Comment: Thanks @bluefeet your in-depth response is much appreciated.