# Query written to pull rows into columns without aggregation is jumbling the columns rather than listing them in order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

TL;DR: Around 1800 functions are turned into columns for "pivot" but they are not being called in order, such that function_376 is consistently called first then "random" others and not all roles have that many functions and it's pulling nulls. How do I get it to pull the functions in order?

I am trying to create a query to produce a result set that can be easily copy and pasted into Excel in a human readable fashion. The normal result set from my query pulls two columns, role and function, with a row for each distinct pair. My objective is to pull the functions all onto the same line and have a column for each function assigned to the role. The closest I have gotten is to repurpose a script I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857737/sql-server-rows-to-columns-without-aggregation) but the problem I am running into is that the query to return the results is jumbling the columns. It is not returning them in the order row, function1,function2, etc. and as result is pocked with NULLs which is making the output virtually useless. The @cols query is pulling the functions together in a consistent order every time I run it but it is not in numerical order, it appears random. Each Function_N column represents the Nth function associated with the role so if I could get the @cols query to build in order, then this would work.

How can I rewrite this so that the output will have the functions listed in numerical order such that the results are left justified?

Code and screenshot of results shown below.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#roles', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #roles;

CREATE TABLE #roles([role] VARCHAR(MAX), [function] VARCHAR(MAX))
Insert into #roles 
select distinct r.r_desc, f.f_desc
from roles r
join role_functions rf on rf_rid = r_id
join Functions f on f_id = rf_fid
where r.r_Active = 'y'


 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' 
                      + QUOTENAME(rn) 
                    from
                    (
                      select 'function_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by [role] 
                                order by [role]) as varchar(20)) rn
                      from #roles
                    ) src
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [Role],' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select [Role], [function],
                  ''function_''+cast(row_number() over(partition by [role] 
                                              order by [role]) as varchar(20)) rn
                from #roles
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max([function])
                for rn in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

[Image of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euFgx.png)

Comment: The problem is with the distinct, It doesn't maintain order

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer and then accept it in order to help other users with similar problems

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! The distinct was a nod in the right direction. I also needed another temp table for calculating the max column count and then I used a variable to pass that into the first stuff function. See below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#roles', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #roles;


  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#funtcnt', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #funtcnt;



CREATE TABLE #roles([role] VARCHAR(MAX), [function] VARCHAR(MAX))
Insert into #roles 
select distinct r.r_desc, f.f_desc
from roles r
join role_functions rf on rf_rid = r_id
join Functions sf on f_id = rf_fid
where r.r_Active = 'y'

select [role], count([function]) as [count]
INTO #funtcnt
from #roles  group by [role]

declare @topcount varchar(max) = (select top 1 [role] from #funtcnt order by [count] desc)



 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' 
                      + QUOTENAME(rn) 
                    from
                    (
                      select 'function_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by [role] 
                                order by [role]) as varchar(20)) rn
                      from #roles where [role] = @topcount
                    ) src
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [Role],' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select [Role], [function],
                  ''function_''+cast(row_number() over(partition by [role] 
                                              order by [role]) as varchar(20)) rn
                from #roles
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max([function])
                for rn in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```