# Split Column value into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

the Column that I wanna split has a lot of values:

```
Col1   Col2

val1   stuff
val2   stuff
val3   stuff
val4   stuff
....   .....
```

The expected output:

```
val1   val2  val3  val4   ....
stuff  stuff stuff stuff
```

I tried the pivot method but since my column have a lot of values I didn't know how to adapt it and make it work.

Comment: Dynamic Sql.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883957/tsql-pivot-long-list-of-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Col1) 
            FROM t c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select *
                from t
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(Col2)
                for Col1 in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e61b/3)